# Did Facebook ever had a dislike button?

Tags: facebook

I know they are not planing on implementing it, but did Facebook ever had a dislike button or a thumbs down button of any kind?

Also, I'm not talking about the unlike button that appears after you "like" something.

Comment: Although I'm having trouble finding any proof, some people have said that way back when Facebook was first gaining popularity (2004-2005ish), that there was a thumbs down button.

Comment: @ben.. nope :) and that's why you having trouble finding any proof. If they had the thumbs down button, they would have a thumbs up and there wouldn't be much noise when they introduced the like.. which would basically the same thing with the thumbs up :)

Comment: Yesss ive been on fb 10 yrs since 2004 when only college students with an school email could join they removed the dislike button quickly but i do remeber dislike liking a few things

Comment: Human memory is faulty. Please back this up with a source. All the reliable sources I've seen says Facebook never had such a thing.

Comment: @Lipis - They DID have a thumbs down button. See http://www.insidefacebook.com/2008/04/15/facebook-simplifies-news-feed-interface/

Comment: I know for a fact they did have one when they first started.  Ads would pop-up and you could thumbs down an ad so it would never show up again.  It was a feature added by the co-founder of Facebook (who relinquished his citizenship and moved to Singapore just to avoid paying taxes on his billion).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the closest thing is the `X` button that appears in the upper right corner of ads and other items, which allows you to mark an ad as uninteresting, but this doesn't share anything with your friends as with the Like button.  Also answers in the Help section have Helpful and Unhelpful options.

The "Like" button started out internally as an "Awesome" button, as recounted in [this history](http://www.quora.com/Facebook-Inc-company/Whats-the-history-of-the-Awesome-Button-that-eventually-became-the-Like-button-on-Facebook) by Facebook Director of Product Engineering Andrew Bosworth, and did not have any negative counterpart.

If someone dislikes something that you posted it is usually not particularly helpful to see that they dislike it without any reason given (unless your post is expressing dislike and they are actually trying to agree with you).  Even if you can guess the reason they dislike it because you know the person, the dislike is likely to be misinterpreted by others.  Comments are usually a better way to express dislike so that you can make your objection clear.

Comment: Actually, the closest thing they had was a thumbs down button: http://www.insidefacebook.com/2008/04/15/facebook-simplifies-news-feed-interface/

Answer (score 5):

They did have a 'thumbs down' and a 'thumbs up' button.

At one point they removed both buttons because they were not seen as useful. In return we got the 'Like' button a while later.

One instance talking about the renewal of the interface:

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2008/04/15/facebook-simplifies-news-feed-interface/

Answer (score 3):

No. I seem to recall Facebook saying it won't have one because it create a negative experience when browsing the website.

It makes sense why they wouldn't, happy users etc, but there are times when I'd like to dislike things people say.

Comment: They did have a thumbs down button: http://www.insidefacebook.com/2008/04/15/facebook-simplifies-news-feed-interface/

Answer (score 0):

There was once a dislike button or thumbs down I remember it specifically, nobody seems to remember and the Internet doesn't have anything about it, there definitely was though when Facebook first came out and there was always a like button since it began.

Comment: What's your source? Human memory is faulty.

Comment: @AlE. http://www.insidefacebook.com/2008/04/15/facebook-simplifies-news-feed-interface/

Comment: That's not a dislike button. They just used "thumbs up/down" for sliders for an experiment with the news feed. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes yes there was originally a dislike button.
Sad people don't rember it!!!!
I am in this moment arguing with my girlfriend about this actual fact. 
She says no
I say yes

But the truth is there was a dislike button I am 100% sure on that fact!!

I actually remember pressing it on numerous occasions at my friend Luke as a joke!!!

There was one and any fool saying there wasn't just is a Facebook NOOB

Simple

Comment: Any references? Ivy League schools got FB for active students before anyone else my freshman year, and I don't remember it existing (though there were spinoff dislike apps)

Comment: Proof or it didn't happen. I can point you to multiple references showing people remembering things that never happened.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed there WAS once a "dislike" button on Facebook.  They removed it because of divisiveness.  As if no way could be divisive otherwise.  LOL

Comment: Source or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

They will have a dislike *sticker* for the Messenger app.

[Source](http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2013/12/17/facebook-gets-sassy-new-like-stickers-messenger/).

Answer (score -1):

NO. - http://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2010/10/10/facebook-dislike-button-why-it-will-never-happen/

Comment: Part of the article would be a nice to have here and of course the link to the original ;)

Comment: http://www.insidefacebook.com/2008/04/15/facebook-simplifies-news-feed-interface/